# US2599667A - incorrect classification

Tags: audio, incorrect, category, tape, splice

US2599667A - 'Splicing Block' - is categorized as

G03D15/043 - Cutting or splicing of filmstrips

But the invention is more correctly seen as an influential early example of a splicing block for magnetic audio tape.

Comment: Your question is ___ ?

Comment: Good point. I guess, How can I report this, or make someone aware of this? Thank you! And apologies for the vagueness, noob here.

Comment: Seriously, please edit so that there is a question to be answered.

Comment: It’s an old expired patent and really classifications hardly matter. Please edit the question adding your intent and we’ll try to answer.

Comment: Hi Eric, many thanks for responding. Yes it's an old patent but it is historically significant. The invention is in the Smithsonian. https://americanhistory.si.edu/collections/search/object/nmah_1347316. So I thought it would be useful for historians to be able to browse for this via the category facets. - So my question is: How can I edit the category metadata, or contact someone who can? Hope this counts as an appropriate question. But if it is not, then I am more than happy to delete it. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question with the additional context of your last comment. Comments are not meant to be the question. If you do that, I'll try to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to try to answer what I think the question is based on your comments. In short, I've found classification codes to be somewhat imprecise in organizing patent literature. Often there is no code that specifically covers the invention so the USPTO picks what it believes is the best alternative. No one I know in the modern age of computer based full text search engines relies solely on classification codes to do patent searching.

As for the the question embedded in your comment:

> How can I edit the category metadata, or contact someone who can?

Patent [US2599667A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2599667A/en?oq=US2599667A) has the following stated in its first paragraph.

> This invention relates to splicing blocks, such as are used in
> splicing film and sound recording tape, and specifically it refers to
> a block which is particularly suitable for editing sound recording
> tape.

The classification code isn't completely off the mark based on this. In any case, you can't edit it yourself and I highly doubt there is anyone at the USPTO who is willing or interested in changing classification codes for 70 year old patents.

Comment: many thanks for your reply, I understand. I'll consider my poorly structured query to have been answered by you, and acknowledge that the existing classification for this patent will stand. Once again thank you for your responses!

Comment: @mjkhoo If you wish to formally accept the answer, you can click the check mark.